# How can I enable syntax highlighting in VS 2015 for my text/ng-template scripts?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How can I enable HTML syntax highlighting in VS 2015 for my HTML inside a text/ng-template script?

For some reason, my visual studio is not color highlighting the syntax properly.

[image: Syntax Highlight]